# Using C++ I need to change a selection sort into an insertion sort

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, insertion-sort

I have a program in which I have to change the selection sort into an insertion sort in a C++ program using Visual Studio 2010. The following code is what I have showing the selection sort:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {
                 int data[] = {5,6,7,1,2,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,0,7,8,5,3,2,6,8};
                 if (button1->Text == "Start") 
                 {
                     panel1->Visible = true;
                     button1->Text = "Sort";
                     messageLabel->Text="Unsorted Array";
                     DrawArray(data, 20);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(ascButton->Checked )
                     {
                         selectionSort(data,20,1);
                         messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Ascending";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         selectionSort(data,20,2);
                         messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Descending";
                     }
                     DrawArray(data, 20);
                 }
             }

    private: System::Void selectionSort(int array[], int n,int ascending)
             {
                 int temp,index; // temporary variable used for swapping and index
                 int i, j;
                 for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
                 {
                     index = i;
                     for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
                     {
                        if(ascending==1)
                        {
                            if (array[j] < array[index])
                            {
                                 index = j;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (array[j] > array[index])
                            {
                                 index = j;
                            }
                        }
                     }
                    if (index != i) 
                    {
                          temp = array[i];
                          array[i] = array[index];
                          array[index] = temp;
                    }
                 } // end for

             } // end method selectionSort
```

I have the following changes implemented and the program runs without any errors but the data doesn't look like it is being sorted. Here is the following updated code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
             {
                 int data[] = {5,6,7,1,2,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,0,7,8,5,3,2,6,8};
                 if (button1->Text == "Start") 
                 {
                     panel1->Visible = true;
                     button1->Text = "Sort";
                     messageLabel->Text="Unsorted Array";
                     DrawArray(data, 20);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(ascButton->Checked )
                     {
                        insertionSort(data,20,1);
                         messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Ascending";
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         insertionSort(data,20,2);
                         messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Descending";
                     }
                     DrawArray(data, 20);
                 }
             }

    private: System::Void insertionSort(int array[], int n,int ascending)
             {
                 int data[]= {5,6,7,1,2,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,0,7,8,5,3,2,6,8};
                 int vacant; // Position of last vacated element
                 int temp; // Temporary copy of unsorted value
                 int i;
                 for (i=0; i < n-1; i++)
                 {
                     temp = data[i+1]; // Copy first unsorted value
                     for (vacant = i+1; 
                         ((vacant > 0) && (data[vacant-1] > temp));
                         vacant--)
                     {
                         data[vacant] = data[vacant-1]; // Shift data up
                     } // End inner loop
                 data[vacant] = temp; // Insert value into vacated element
                 } // End outer loop
             }
```

Comment: can you please also post the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I should word the coding to change this sort. This program runs perfect as it is with the selection sort; but I need to try to change the sort into an insertion sort.

Comment: Is there a reason why you keep deducting points from me????? I'm asking a question for some help and guidence and I keep getting deducted points???? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If this forum is not for help then I'll take my business somewhere else. It's not right to be pentialized without reasons

Comment: I am new too. I guess your points got deducted because you should not keep a question which is too open. The question you asked should reflect the trials that you made and the problems that you faced. If you had added more stuff like, here is what i tried and here is where i failed, I guess people wouldnt have deducted points from you

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code should be changed:

```
if(ascButton->Checked )
{
    //selectionSort(data,20,1);
    insertionSort(data, 20, 1);
    messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Ascending";
}
else
{
    //selectionSort(data,20,2);
    insertionSort(data, 20, 1);
    messageLabel->Text="Sorted Array - Descending";
}
```

Also declare a private: `System::Void insertionSort(int array[], int n,int ascending)` just like `System::Void selectionSort(int array[], int n,int ascending)` and fill up your insertion sort code there.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I have already made the changes in the areas that you have addressed here and this information is updated in the post above. Again thanks for answering my original post.